# Why does template inheritance in Django not show error?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm not seeing an error when template inheritance seems to fail. I don't see content from the child template but I don't see a 'TemplateNotFound' error. If I change the path to the parent template to 'notthefilename.html' I still don't see an error. Is there a way to make template inheritance fail noisily? I have no idea why this is not working even though I have a similar inheritance in a adjacent folder that is working as expected.

**generic_create.html** The text 'hello2' *is* rendering.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}


<div style= "padding-top: 30px">
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% if model_name == 'TransactionsTable' %}
        <div>
            {% block transactions_create %}
            hello2
            {% endblock transactions_create %}             
        </div>        
        {% else %}
        {{ form |crispy }}
        {% endif %}
        <div id="container">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" value="Save"> 
        <a href="{{ view.get_success_url }}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        <div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**transactions_create.html** - The content 'Hello1' *is not* rendering

```
{% extends "generic_create.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block transactions_create %}

Hello1

{% endblock transactions_create %}
```

Comment: It's not clear what is not working here. Which template are you rendering?

Comment: My view is rendering generic_create.html. ohhh do I have it backwards? Should I be rendering transaction_create.html?

Comment: Yes. You must render the child, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daniel Roseman's comment I realized I was performing the inheritance backwards. I was also over-complicating things. Using the `include` tag I was able to perform the sort of inheritance I was hoping to achieve very easily.

**generic_create.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}


<div style= "padding-top: 30px">
    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {% if model_name == 'TransactionsTable' %}
        <div>
        {% include "transactions_create.html" %}     #NOTE: Here I removed the block and added 'include'.    
        </div>        
        {% else %}
        {{ form |crispy }}
        {% endif %}
        <div id="container">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" value="Save"> 
        <a href="{{ view.get_success_url }}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        <div>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**transactions_create.html**

```
Hello1 #removed all of the extend and 'block' code. 'include' just renders the html directly.
```

That's it! 'include' really simplified things.